# Does Photo SE do any marketing?

Tags: discussion, community

I'm fairly new to the SE community as a whole, but really enjoy the site's functioning and the way it goes about things.

After being here a short time - it seems obvious that there are a relatively few amount of players that contribute to +80% of the questions being asked.

And, no doubt about it, they are incredibly smart players.

But, there are also questions that I see that receive very little attention - and it seems that if we had a larger community, they may stand a chance of being answered.

What does SE do to grow the community? I ask because I actually wondered here from the Salesforce SE, but have never seen any sort of marketing for either.

Also - if there is a marketing plan and governing body, how would one get involved with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Search Engine Optimization* seems to be the primary strategy to attract new users. For the most part the SE sites are all fairly well represented in search engine results that use terms that appear in a question here.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly word of mouth and cross site promotion with other SE's at times as well as organic search traffic.